# CSS: How avoid a transition rotation break at 360°?

Tags: javascript, css

I currently implement a compass in JavaScript/CSS.

Global implementation works fine.

However, the cursor of compass move with jolt. I implemented the transition `ease-in-out` in CSS to avoid this issue.

From 0 to 359 degree, the cursor turn fine in counter-clockwise (With CSS transition).

But if the angle is set from 356 degree to 1 degree, the CSS transition rotate the cursor in clockwise so with big gap (355 deg instead 5 deg) .

Is it a way to avoid this gap or other solution to implement a good transition?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep incrementing beyond 360. CSS will figure it out.

Comment: I think this is a good question because I'm really not sure if there is any impact letting the rotation value run up forever.

Comment: can u implement a jsfiddle? it's hard to know what's going on without the actual code

Comment: The easiest is keep incrementing like Diodeus says. Other way is using the javascript animation API to have more control on the animations.

Comment: Please share a code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use something like anime.js its great to handle animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for each idea.

So, by CSS, solution is to keep incrementing beyond 360 like Diodeus say. But in my case, computed angle is scaled between 0 and 360°.

By JS, we can use anime.js but I preferred to code my proper animation function. This function do the following:

- compute angle in clockwise between current position and destination
- compute angle in counter-clockwise between current position and destination
- compute the minimum angle between the both (it's the shortest way)
- For 5 sample, start a Timeout 5 times and add [minimum angle / 5] to the current position in order to reach destination.